# Segue from Static Cells to Dynamic TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a TableViewController that has static cells inside groups. I want to perform segue from some of the static cells, but also somehow know which cell triggered the segue in the segued TableViewController.

I ctrl + dragged from each cell to the destination TVC, added segue identifiers and created a class for TVC.

I this approach, but the segue doesn't work. It doesn't print `XOX` either

```
class MainTableViewController {

  viewDidLoad() {
     tableView.delegate = self
     tableView.dataSource = self
  }

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      print("XOX")
      if segue.identifier == "MainToA" {        
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailTableViewController {
                destination.page = "A"
        }
      }

     if segue.identifier == "MainToB" {        
       if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailTableViewController {
               destination.page = "B"
       }
     }
  }
```

---

```
class DetailTableViewController {

    var page = String()

    viewDidLoad() {
         print(page)
    }
}
```

Am I missing out something or completely out of track? Why doesn't the segue work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and the segues work correctly with connection to individual UITableViewCell

> You can see in the image the triggered segue part

[image]

Please make sure you have connected the segue from the cell instead of any subview inside it.

> Edit

From the chat it appears you have a `UITapGesture` which takes up the touch of the view.
To avoid this i would suggest to removeTapGesture and use tableView `didSelectRow` methods to detect touches on view

Comment: It's exactly same for me, too. I gave segue to the cell, and added segue an identifier. When I click on the segue, the cell get highlighted, also selection is as same as your screenshot. Did you add anything in your MainVC? What's wrong with mine?

Comment: try coming to the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Did you subclass UITableViewController?  Did you assign that subclass in Interface Builder?  Did you make sure NOT to implement override func `numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int` 
so that your static cells actually appear?

When you ctrl+dragged did you link up Triggered Segues by Selection, not Accessory action?

Comment: What do you mean by subclassing? I don't use `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and my static cells appear. When I ctrl+dragged, it's selection, also when I click on the cell, under connection inspector it's selection. Also, I gave the identifier to the segue.. What else might be the problem?

Comment: Your class MainTableViewController has to subclass UITableViewController.   So your class definition should look like 'class MainTableViewController:: UITableViewController {'  After you've done that, you need to click on your UITableViewController object in interface builder and change it's class from UITableViewController to MainTableViewController.  And you need to go read about cocoa subclassing.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Table View is working fine. The cells are filled and getting/modifying data from ViewController. It's just the segue not working

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the *Selection* property in your **Table View Static Content**

*Attributes inspector*, as shown in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrGb5.png).